# Mongoose Queries Find

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, find

I have table like this:

```
"products": [
        {
            "reviews": [],
            "_id": "5ece6d09cab302507c5d147e",
            "category": {
                "_id": "5ece6c07cab302507c5d1478",
                "type": "Marketing",
=
```

And I want to get all products, with 'category.type' == 'Marketing'.

This is working in that way:

```
let products = await Product.find({ 'category': '5ece6c07cab302507c5d1478' })
```

But I don't want to use ID for search, but instead word "Marketing".

This returns nothing...

```
let products = await Product.find({ 'category.type': 'Marketing' })
```

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
let products = await Product.find({ "category.type": {$eq: "Marketing"} });
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but that returns me error: "Can't use $elemMatch"

Comment: Sorry My bad, $elemMatch is for search an object into an array. can you please edit your post and show me your mongodb schema?